# Adding to an XSL Variable in a for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I wish to append the value of a variable to itself each time it iterates through a for-each, problem is I'm not sure on how to go about this. Here is what I currently have:

```
<xsl:variable name="lineQty" select="0" />
<xsl:for-each select="/*/*/*/*/*/xsales:CustInvoiceTrans">
  <xsl:value-of select="$lineQty + (xsales:LineNum * xsales:Qty)" />
</xsl:for-each>
<test>
  <xsl:value-of select="$lineQty" />
</test>
```

This just outputs 0

### Edit

I changed it to the following:

```
<xsl:variable name="lineQty">
  <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/*/*/*/xsales:CustInvoiceTrans">
    <xsl:value-of select="xsales:LineNum * xsales:Qty" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

But this outputs `12345`. The reason for this is that it's done 1x1, 2x1, 3x1, 4x1, 5x1 as my 5 lines each have a quantity of 1. So all that needs to happen now is adding up these values, is that possible?

Comment: XSLT wont actually allow you to reassign a value to a variable - theyre fixed - hence the 0 here.

Comment: Is there any other way of achieving this? I wish to add the result of each `xsales:LineNum * xsales:Qty` together?

Comment: Can you add the source xml as well?

Comment: The values of `xsales:LineNum` and `xsales:Qty` are present and correct, as I use the for-each in another place on my xslt too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using XSLT 2.0? If so, try this:

```
    <xsl:variable name="seq" as="xs:double*">
        <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/*/*/*/xsales:CustInvoiceTrans">
            <xsl:sequence select="xs:double(xsales:LineNum) *  xs:double(xsales:Qty)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <test>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum($seq)"/>
    </test>
```

EDIT

@Markus suggested even shorter version:

```
    <test>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(/*/*/*/*/*/xsales:CustInvoiceTrans/(xs:double(xsales:LineNum) * xs:double(xsales:Qty)))" />
    </test>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You can compress that into: `sum(/*/*/*/*/*/xsales:CustInvoiceTrans/(xs:double(xsales:LineNum) *  xs:double(xsales:Qty)))`

Comment: I am using XSLT 2.0 but I dont have the xs namespace it seems? As I get this error: `Undeclared namespace prefix (xs)`

Comment: xs stands for XML Schema namespace:
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 

It's not needed in the solution proposed by @MarkusJarderot